# string is palindrome or not with python - UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, string

I create a code to test if the string is palindrome or not. The test pass exept when I give the function one character. at this time I got this error:

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'is_palindrome' referenced before assignment

```
"""
Given a string str, return true if the str can be palindrome and false if not.

Input: str = "aba"
Output: true


Input: str = "abc"
Output: false
"""

def validPalindrome(str: str) -> bool:
  for i in range(len(str)//2):
    is_palindrome = False
    if str[i] == str[-i-1]:
      is_palindrome = True
  if is_palindrome:
    return True
  else:
    return False


print(validPalindrome('aba'))
print(validPalindrome('abc'))
print(validPalindrome('a'))
```

Comment: The loop is never entered for a one-character string, and thus `is_palindrome` is never set.

Comment: To add further to @9769953 comment above, rather than setting `is_palindrome` to `True` for each matched character, please try to set it to `False` for any mismatch. That way, you are able to set an initial value for the flag. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71717021/13658816) below.

Comment: On an unrelated note, the function would be complete as `return str ==str[::-1]`, also, try to avoid naming variables the same as keywords.

Comment: thank you @9769953 for your comment now am aware of that scope error

Comment: OOOOh the best solution ever. Thank you @AnshumaanMishra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `if is_palindrome` in line 6 of your function, it should have been defined before. if your input is a single character, your input length is 1, and thus 1//2 = 0. program never enters the loop. and thus `is_palindrome` is never defined. I think changing the program to this would help.

```py
def validPalindrome(str: str) -> bool:
  is_palindrome = True
  for i in range(len(str)//2):
    if str[i] != str[-i-1]:
      is_palindrome = False
      break
  return is_palindrome
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `is_palindrome` variable in the right scope:

```py
def validPalindrome(str: str) -> bool:
  is_palindrome = False
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you @Mohammad Jafari for your help. I have to be aware with declaring variables in right scope